# Given $f(z) = \int_{\gamma} \frac{\sin \zeta + e^{i\zeta}}{(\zeta-z)^{2} } d\zeta$, find $f'(\frac{\pi}{4})$ if $\gamma$ is the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**: Assume that $\gamma$ is the positively oriented unit circle $|z| = 1$ in $C$. Let

$f(z) = \displaystyle \int_{\gamma} \frac{\sin \zeta + e^{i\zeta}}{(\zeta-z)^{2} } d\zeta$

Find $f'(\frac{\pi}{4})$.

**Comments**: This is a problem from an old exam in complex analysis. I have not found similar problems in my textbook so I would be grateful if someone could show me how to solve it (is it a "Dirichlet problem"?). I am studying for an exam and I would like to know how to deal with this problem type. All input appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: double hint: the integral formula can be extended to deal with derivatives

Comment: @BettyMock Okay I have that formula $f^{(n)}(z) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(s)}{(s-z)^{n+1}} \, ds$, but I am feeling a little dense at the moment, so can you clarify for me how to use it for this problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Sid Put in $n=1$. Your $f(z)$ in the problem statement is then $\pi i g'(z)$ where $g(z)=\sin\zeta+e^{i\zeta}$. Got it?

Comment: @Sid To clear confusion you may want to change one of the two different expressions you refer to with $f(z)$ (one in problem statement, different $f$ in your formula).

Comment: @Evan You are right, but I can't edit the comment anymore.

Comment: @Connor I'm not sure what is meant by $g(z)=\sin\zeta+e^{i\zeta}$, since $\zeta$ and $z$ are different variables. But by plugging into the formula I get that $f'(\frac{\pi}{2}) =    \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{\sin\zeta+e^{i\zeta}}{(\zeta-\frac{\pi}{2})^{2}} d\zeta$ and I can solve the integral by means of residue calculus. Is this right?

Comment: @Sid Sorry about that, you're right. It should be all $z$'s instead of the $\zeta$'s. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g(z)=\sin z+e^{iz}$. Then $g(z)$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $\{|z|\le 1\}$, so by Cauchy's integral formula:
$$g'(z)=\frac{2}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{\sin \zeta+e^{i\zeta}}{(\zeta-z)^2}\, d\zeta$$
From this, we see that the $f(z)$ in the problem statement is $\pi i g'(z)$. Now differentiate $g(z)=\sin z+e^{iz}$ twice to get an expression for $f'(z)$:
$$f'(z)=\pi i g''(z)=\pi i\left(-\sin z-e^{iz}\right)$$
$$f'\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\pi i g''\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\pi i \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-e^{i\pi/4}\right)=\frac{\pi-2i}{\sqrt{2}}$$